# Print floating point number using printf() at ARM Cortex M0 uart console

Tags: c, gcc, arm, embedded, atmelstudio

I configured Atmel's ARM Cortex M0's UART for printing strings and integers at the console using std C function printf() in Atmel studio 7.

**Case I**

I am trying to make printf() type of function print floating point values and for that I followed following suggestions to do so:

[arm-none-eabi-gcc : Printing float number using printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703307/arm-none-eabi-gcc-printing-float-number-using-printf)

and later on I edited/added the linker flags following texts separately at different time :

```
-lc -u _printf_float
-lc -lrdimon -u _printf_float
```

**Case II**

Though I could not understand everything they said but I followed some of the suggestions to edit makefile from this forum too.

[Printf/Sprintf for float point variables not working](https://answers.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+question/245658)

and added following text inside the makefile

```
ldflags-gnu-y += -lc -u _printf_float
```

Makefile Path (Atmel Studio 7, using ASF) :   *../src/ASF/sam0/utils/make/Makefile.sam.in*

Now in the main.c I used printf() for printing floating point number as :

```
float a = 345.65412;
char buffr[20];         
/* --- Print Float using printf only --- */
printf("Float Number 1 : %f\r\n", a);   
/* --- Print Float using sprintf ---*/
sprintf(buffr, "Float Number ( Using Sprintf) : %3.3f\r\n", a); 
printf(buffr);
```

Output on a UART console app.:

**Case I**:

```
Float Number 1 : 2.000000
Float Number ( Using Sprintf) : -0.000
```

**Case II**:

```
Float Number 1 : 
Float Number ( Using Sprintf) :
```

Does anyone know configuring linker to make printf(), sprintf() or vprintf() work for printing floating point number on the console for ARM Cortex M0 (SAM B 11) in Atmel Studio 7 ?

Comment: Some other links I followed which I could not include on the question : 
[Printf with floating point support in armgcc](http://atmel.force.com/support/articles/en_US/FAQ/Printf-with-floating-point-support-in-armgcc)
[Using floats with sprintf, gcc-arm-none-eabi, nRF51822](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/5076/using-floats-with-sprintf-gcc-arm-none-eabi-nrf51822/)

Answer (score 1):

You buffer is too small for your data

```
char buffr[20];
```

have to be at least (considering `0.0` as format output)

```
char buffr[38];
```

The small buffer causes a "write out of bounds" of the array. It means you have a [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and `a` variable is polluted.

[sprintf](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm) is different than `printf`.
It copy all chars to the output buffer and you must grant space for text and for all chars that will be added by format specifiers.

In your specific case:

- `Float Number ( Using Sprintf) :` --> takes 32 chars
- `%3.3f` --> takes 7 chars due to the real output of `345.654`
- `\r\n` --> takes 2 chars
- a final byte is needed for the null terminator `'\0'`

That menas your buffer have to be:

```
char buffr[42];
```

Comment: Increased the size of array, but problem not solved though ?
If at least 37 bytes of space was required how those strings came to get printed on console (as in both case I and II) ?

Comment: In your specific case you need `char buffr[42];` as I described. BTW what happening to you is (as I wrote) [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) that means the output is undefined.